# codeigniter - using helper in controller doesn't work

Tags: php, codeigniter, controller, helper

I need to use a function in multiple controllers.
So I though about using a custom helper, but it seems I can't get it to work. (It works in the view, but I need it in the controller)

It gives me following Fatal Error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method Developers::checkIfLoggedIn() in
>   /application/controllers/developers.php on line 12

Is it a smart move to use a helper to use a function in multiple controllers, or should I do it otherwise.

Thanks in Advance,
Mark

**EDIT:**
Controller file:

```
if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Developers extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
         parent::__construct()
         $this->load->helper('form');
         $this->load->helper('url');
         $this->load->helper('login');

         //helper function
         checkIfLoggedIn($this->session->userdata('loggedIn'));
    }
}
```

Helper file:

```
if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

if (!function_exists('checkIfLoggedIn'))
{
    function checkIfLoggedIn($session_loggedIn)
    {
        $loggedIn = $session_loggedIn;
        if($loggedIn == false)
        {
            redirect('login/');
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I had the same problem and I created one base controller with that function and extended that in each controller because helpers are for views

Comment: Alright, thanks. I'll think I'll do that then

Comment: Did you auto loaded the helper? Or in the controller, before you want to use it?

Comment: @EaterOfCorpses, helpers are not only for `views` you can use it in controllers too. [Read here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/helpers.html).

Comment: @SheikhHeera Im sorry, I thought the system in Zend and CodeIgniter were the same

Comment: it's ok and you should not be sorry for that just make the `OP` clear by yourself. :-)

Comment: I tried your code in my editor and it works absolutely fine. Did you autoload your helper in config/autoload.php ? [DijkeMark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1074186/dijkemark)

Answer (score 19):

In your controller you are using it in wrong way, it's not a method of controller so you can't use `$this` to call it.

> A helper can be loaded anywhere within your controller functions (or
>   even within your View files, although that's not a good practice), as
>   long as you load it before you use it. You can load your helpers in
>   your controller constructor so that they become available
>   automatically in any function, or you can load a helper in a specific
>   function that needs it.

To load a helper you can use

```
$this->load->helper('name'); // name is the name of the file without extention
```

> Unlike most other systems in CodeIgniter, Helpers are not written in
>   an Object Oriented format. They are simple, procedural functions. Each
>   helper function performs one specific task, with no dependence on
>   other functions.

So, to call a helper function in a controller you should not use

```
$this->function_name();
```

instead use

```
function_name();
```

For example if you have a helper function in a helper file named `myCustomHelper.php` as follows

```
function myHelper()
{
    // code
}
```

then you can load it in the controller and call it as follows

```
$this->load->helper('myCustomHelper');
myHelper(); // call the function
```

but it's better to load helpers in the constructor so it'll be available through the whole script.

**Update:** If your helper file's name is `login_helper.php` then you can use it in your controller as follows

```
$this->load->helper('login_helper');
checkIfLoggedIn($this->session->userdata('loggedIn'));
```

[**Read more here**](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/helpers.html).

Comment: I tried calling the function with $this->, yet it still can't find the function

Comment: @DijkeMark, no, you should not call the function with `$this` just call using function name, i.e. `myFunctionName();`.

Comment: I am sorry, that was what I meant. :) I tpyed with, but I meant without. However, it still can't find my function.

Comment: Did you load the helper file using `$this->load->helper('filenamewithoutExt')` ?

Comment: Yes, I did, in the constructor. The helper is located in application/helpers. Everything people tell, I did correct. It is strange it still can't find my function

Comment: Can you post the code you are using in your controller, only the helper related part would be helpful.

Comment: Sorry about that, should have posted it earlier. I edited my main post

Comment: @DijkeMark, where have you loaded your helper file ? I just can see two helper files (form and url) are loaded but not your custom helper file and what is the name of your helper file ?

Comment: Oops, my edit was not complete yet. :p srry about that. The name of the file is login_helper.php

Comment: @DijkeMark, Check the update in my answer and let me know what you got ?

Answer (score 4):

Ok, I know this question has been asked 5 months ago but maybe some people will find this useful. I had just had the same problem and discovered that the filename of my helper functions was a filename that was already used by CodeIgniter.

So if you don't get the warning: 'Unable to load the requested file', 
but instead get the warning: 'Fatal error: Call to undefined function [function_name], you're probably using a filename that already exists natively.

Comment: You absolute legend. Just ran into this problem and you potentially saved me hours :D

Answer (score 1):

Helpers are the ideal way to declare global functions in codeigniter and what you are doing is correct. Following are just few points that will help you.

- Load all helpers through single line instead of separate lines.

  ```
  $this->load->helper('form');
  $this->load->helper('url');
  $this->load->helper('login');
  ```

  ```
  $this->load->helper(array('form','url','login'));
  ```
- If you want to make it global across all the controller files, then you can put it in the autoload.php file located in '`config/`' directory.
  Update the `$autoload['helper']` variable as follows:

  ```
  $autoload['helper'] = array('url','site');
  ```

Source: [How to create & call global PHP functions in CodeIgniter](https://webolute.com/blog/programming/how-to-create-call-global-php-functions-in-codeigniter)

Answer (score 0):

Instead create a library class and define your function there. Then load the library in the controller and call the function of library. You can load library in any controller and use its methods.

Comment: Helpers could be used in controllers in `CI` [CodeIgniter helpers](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/helpers.html).

Answer (score 0):

On a related matter: caution when putting $this->load in the __constructor: in PHP you must then then explicitly call parent::__construct(); otherwise the parent constructor is no longer called, leaving $this->load undefined. The above solution does it correctly, but it's easy to overlook.

```
class My extends CI_Controller {
public function __construct() { 
parent::__construct();
$this->load->helper('url'); }
```

If you don't do this, you'll get the error message that My::$load does not exist and the helper will not load.