# How can I get radio button values from code igniter form into controller?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-form-helper

in view

```
$male=array('id'=>'2','name'=>'gen');
$female=array('id'=>'3','name'=>'gen');
echo "<label>Gender : <label>"." ".form_radio($male)."Male".form_radio($female)."Female"."<br>";
```

How can i get this in controller??

My Controller

```
public function index()
{
    $this->load->view('include/header');
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->view('data');
    $this->load->view('include/footer');
}

public function formHandler()
{
    $data = array('name'=>$_POST['name'],'age'=>$_POST['age'],'gen'=>$_POST['gen'],'a‌​dd'=>$_POST['add']);
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    echo $data['name'];
    //echo $data['age'];
    //echo $data['add'];
}
```

Comment: Are you using a form? Is it a POST or GET form? What does your view code look like? What about the controller code? We can do a better job of helping if you show us the code you are using.

Comment: The code written above is my view code and its a POST frompublic function index()
 {
  $this->load->view('include/header');
  $this->load->helper('form');
  $this->load->view('data');
  $this->load->view('include/footer');
 }
 public function formHandler()
 {
 $data=array('name'=>$_POST['name'],'age'=>$_POST['age'],'gen'=>$_POST['gen'],'add'=>$_POST['add']);
 
 $this->load->library('form_validation');

   
 
     echo $data['name'];
 //echo $data['age'];
 
 //echo $data['add'];
 }

Comment: So what does the rest of the view look like? And the controller? At least the relevant portions would be helpful

Comment: Did you try using the `form_radio()` function exactly like this in the controller at all? [Source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11966355/codeigniter-using-helper-in-controller-doesnt-work)

Comment: @John Sorry - your question was vague. For some reason I thought you were trying to use the view functions in the controller. You should be more clear with the problem you're having

Comment: Thanks Craine Runton!! I got now how to do it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to get a value from the radio buttons, you need to assign them a `value`. For example,

```
<form action="/formHandler" method="post">
$male=array('id'=>'2','name'=>'gen', 'value'=>'m');  
$female=array('id'=>'3','name'=>'gen', 'value'=>'f');  
echo "<label>Gender : <label>"." ".form_radio($male)."Male".form_radio($female)."Female"."<br>";
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Then in the controller you would call

```
$var = $this->input->post('gen');
```

Answer (score 1):

Using

```
$radio_value = $this->input->post('gen');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$radio_value = $this->input->post('gen');
```